# Element not found - Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written a piece of code to login into an application which is working fine. Now I have to click an add button, and I have tried it by Id, `XPath`, `ClassName` but it just gives me the exception of element not found. I thought I should apply an explicit wait, but it also did not work. Please check my code below:

```
public static void Login()

{
    Browser.Url = "http://example.com";
    _username = Browser.FindElement(By.Id("UserName"));
    var password = Browser.FindElement(By.Id("Password"));
    var loginbtn = Browser.FindElement(By.ClassName("btn-primary"));

    _username.SendKeys("admin");
    password.SendKeys("123");
    loginbtn.Click();

    var supplierTab = Browser.FindElement(By.Id("mainSupplier"));
    supplierTab.Click();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Browser, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
    IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
    {
       try
        {
            return d.FindElement(By.Id("btnAddSupplier_SupplierForm"));
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    });

    var addbtn = Browser.FindElement(By.Id("btnAddSupplier_SupplierForm"));
    addbtn.Click();

}
```

This always gives an exception on the second last line of code that element not found.

Here is the HTML:

[image]

Comment: `var addbtn = Browser.FindElement(By.Id("btnAddSupplier_SupplierForm"));`

getting error on this line of code.

Comment: So, it wait `20s` then timesout?

Comment: Yes it waits and then shows timeout.

Comment: Any `frame` of `iframe` elements on the page?

Comment: Then, probably the selector is wrong or the `id` is duplicate. Also, `iframe` can create some issues.

Comment: Post the html please!

Comment: Yes the page is having an iframe but my add button is out of that iframe.

Comment: @LittlePanda HTML is now attached with the question, please check. Please right click the image and open it in a new tab in order to view it clearly. I want to click the highlighted button code basically. Thanks.

Comment: Is the element visible? Because the parent div's class is called "hide".

Comment: @Asma: I dont see anything wrong in the code. Maybe you should try adding an explicit wait....ExpectedCondition.presenceOfElementLocated()

Comment: @FrederikDeMets element is visible but it's kept in a hidden field.

Comment: @LittlePanda I did the same, check my code again. I added an explicit wait to find the element.

Comment: If you can location the JS that executes on the OnClick of the ADD button, simply execute that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
public static void Login()

{
    Browser.Url = "http://example.com";
    _username = Browser.FindElement(By.Id("UserName"));
    var password = Browser.FindElement(By.Id("Password"));
    var loginbtn = Browser.FindElement(By.ClassName("btn-primary"));

    _username.SendKeys("admin");
    password.SendKeys("123");
    loginbtn.Click();

    //I think you have mentioned the iframe exist and assuming the element is inside the iframe do the following. If not skip the SwitchTo() part


    //you can use name, css to identify the iframe
    Browser.SwitchTo().Frame(Browser.FindElement(By.XPath("xpath for the iframe")));

    var supplierTab = Browser.FindElement(By.Id("mainSupplier"));
    supplierTab.Click();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Browser, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
    IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
    {
        return d.FindElement(By.Id("btnAddSupplier_SupplierForm"));
    });

    //if you think the id is not unique try using xpath or css
    //even though you added an explicit wait you never used it
    myDynamicElement.Click();

}
```

Comment: No luck, again the timeout exception ;(

Comment: Is it possible to provide more (actual) `html`? Use [gist](https://gist.github.com/) if you want to

Comment: I don't see any reason why it would not do it. Is that element become visible after clicking `var supplierTab = Browser.FindElement(By.Id("mainSupplier"));
    supplierTab.Click();` ?

Comment: "mainSupplier" is already visible. The add button image is also visible. but there is a hidden field which is an anchor tag to that add button to make that add image clickable.

Comment: Well, the `id` you are using is the hidden anchor tag then? that might be the reason

Comment: Let me ask the developer to do something for it :-/

Comment: Sorry couldn't be more help

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the element will be existing in the source code but will not be visible for selenium to perform a click operation. Try the below code which will wait until the element is visible:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(
ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("btnAddSupplier_SupplierForm")));
element.Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would help, but try calling this function before you click on Add button:

```
void waitForPageLoad(WebDriver driver)
    {
        ExpectedCondition<Boolean> pageLoadCondition = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
            }
        };  
        wait.until(pageLoadCondition);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A NoSuchElementException is thrown when the locating mechanism used is not available in the dom.

A TimeoutException is thrown when your expected condition fails to be true within the time limit. An expected condition can be anything, (exists,visibility,attribute value etc...).

First you want to figure out if the element's locating mechanism you are using is indeed not found in the dom. Here is a good way to manually find out.

1. Open chrome and navigate to the page.
2. Open chrome dev tools and click on the console tab.
3. In the text box type $x("//*[@id='btnAddSupplier_SupplierForm']") and hit enter. This will run an xpath query, basically you are looking for any element that has an id attribute with value "btnAddSupplier_SupplierForm".
4. If an element appears in the console and is the correct element then it's likely that you are trying to find an element in the dom before the dom is finished loading. If no element appears in the console then you have a bad locator.

Please report your findings.